# setState for nested objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a nested object as a state and I have a form in a component. I was thinking of updating the state every time the user enter something in the form and to avoid creating many functions for each input I was thinking of creating a single function using switch.

1. Is creating a single function with switch a good idea?
2. How can I update a single nested element of the object?

I have tried with the following code but it doesn't work:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        minutes: null,
        interests: {
          business: false,
          code: false,
          design: false
        },
        errors: []
      }
  }

  updatePreferences = (preferenceName, enteredValue) => {
    switch (preferenceName) {
      case preferenceName === "minutes":
        this.setState({minutes: enteredValue})
        return
      case preferenceName === "business":
        this.setState({interests.business: !this.state.interests.business})
        return
      case default:
        return
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course you can use `switch`, Nothing wrong AFAIK.

And to update nested objects with `setState`. See the example

```
  updatePreferences = (preferenceName, enteredValue) => {
     switch (preferenceName) {
      case preferenceName === "minutes":
        this.setState({minutes: enteredValue});
        return
      case preferenceName === "business":
        this.setState({...this.state, interests: {
          ...this.state.interests,
          business: !this.state.interests.business
        }});
        return
      default:
        return
    }

  }
```

Comment: great! just `default` instead of `case default`

Comment: Sorry, Missed that