# React state. Change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Have a problem with change state. I have some state =

```
id: '',
avatar: '',
steps: 0,
programName: '',
programDate: '',
programPrice: '',
personalInfo: {
  name: '',
  surname: '',
  sex: 'man',
  birthDay: '',
  birthMonth: '',
  birthYear: '',
  familyStatus: '',
  countryBirth: '',
  cityBirth: '',
  birthCitizenship: '',
  currentCitizenship: ''
},
```

How I can change like this property: `this.state.personalInfo.name`??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setState for nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44118037/setstate-for-nested-objects)

Answer (score 0):

Use setState() method to change the
state.

```
this.setState({this.state.personalInfo.name:"new data"});
```

[See more here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/react_native/react_native_state.htm)

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/react_native/react_native_state.htm

Answer (score 0):

This question might be duplicated.

To change the value of nested objects in the state of a component the proper way to do it is:

```
const { personalInfo } = this.state;
this.setState({
  ...this.state,
  personalInfo: {
    ...personalInfo,
    name: 'New Name',
  },
});
```

You have to consider that the `setState()` function needs a new object every time you change the state. The spread operator (`...`) is useful when creating a new object. So basically you have to copy the properties from the previous state and replace the name property of `personalInfo`.